# django-tenant-schemas: How to use with single tenant/without subdomains

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I started using django-tenant-schemas for my project with all data tables (user, etc.) completely separated.

My requirements are that I can deploy the same code base in a private server to a single customer as well as on a cloud for multiple. The routing of django-tenant-schemas does not support that. If I only have a single tenant it will still require a subdomain for the database routing.

Also for localhost development with runserver I now need to add a line to my /etc/hosts to make it work, like:

```
127.0.0.1       testtenant.localhost.com
```

How can I get around that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This custom middleware extends the original one of django-tenant-schemas, checks if only one tenant schemas exists and sets the request database connection to it. With that you can simply create a tenant and continue using e.g. localhost:8000 for you development work as well as hosting it for a single tenant.

```
from django.db import connection
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from tenant_schemas.middleware import TenantMiddleware
from tenant_schemas.utils import get_tenant_model, get_public_schema_name


def get_tenant_schemas():
    ''' Return all tenant schemas '''
    return get_tenant_model().objects.exclude(
        schema_name=get_public_schema_name())


class SchemaRouterMiddleware(TenantMiddleware):
    """
    Extends the original routing middleware from django-tenant-schemas.
    To support both types of deployment (cloud with many tenants vs. single
    tenant on own server) we check if our database holds more than one tenant:
     - Yes: Select schema based on subdomain (= django-tenant-schemas default)
     - No: Always use that single tenant's schema no matter what the
       incoming host name is (ip, domain, subdomain, ...)
    """
    single_tenant = False

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Adding a new tenant will most likely go with a server restart so we can
        avoid querying the table with each request and only do this once here:
        '''
        tenants = get_tenant_schemas()
        if tenants.count() == 1:
            self.single_tenant = tenants[0]

    def process_request(self, request):
        if self.single_tenant:
            connection.set_tenant(self.single_tenant)
            request.tenant = self.single_tenant
            ContentType.objects.clear_cache()
        else:
            super(SchemaRouterMiddleware, self).process_request(request)
```

Set the custom middleware instead of the original one:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( 
    'middleware.apps.schemas.router.SchemaRouterMiddleware',
     ...
)
```